# Series.str.split returns NaN and unexpected data type

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3.8.5, Pandas 1.1.3

`data` variable represents a results set from an API call.

```
import pandas as pd
        
data = [{"results": [{"type": "ID", "value": "1234", "normalized": "1234", "count": 1, "offsets": [{"start": 14, "end": 25}], "id_b": "10"}, {"type": "ID", "value": "5678", "normalized": "5678", "count": 1, "offsets": [{"start": 32, "end": 43}], "id_b": "11"}], "responseHeaders": {"Date": "Tue, 25 May 2021 14:41:28 GMT", "Content-Type": "application/json", "Content-Length": "350", "Connection": "keep-alive", "Server": "openresty", "X-StuffAPI-ProcessedLanguage": "eng", "X-StuffAPI-Request-Id": "abcdef", "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload", "X-StuffAPI-App-Id": "123456789", "X-StuffAPI-Concurrency": "1"}}]
s = pd.Series(data)
s
```

returns

```
0    {'results': [{'type': 'ID', 'value': '1234', '...
dtype: object
```

...which makes sense.

But then, add

```
ss = s.str.split()
ss
```

returns

```
0   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Why `NaN` and why `float64`?  I've also tried with several `str.split` params including different types of patterns for `pat` as well as `expand=True`, but all give the same result.

Ultimately I need to parse those key/values from `data` into separate columns, but right now I just need to get them to be read at all.

Comment: [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) "Splits the string in the Series/Index from the beginning, at the specified delimiter string.". 
Why `NaN`?: "pandas primarily uses NaN to represent missing data" ([src](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#working-with-missing-data)). 
Why `float64`?: `NaN` happens to be of type `float64`. 
What were you trying to do?

Comment: @HenryEcker hi good to see you again.  Yeah that's what I'm trying to determine, what's going wrong.  Ultimately what I'm trying to do is extract data from the `results` string as though I were extracting key-values from a dictionary or JSON object, so I can take those and put them into the columns of a csv file (e.g. a "type" column populated with value "ID", a "value" column populated with value "1234", etc).  The middle part of actually parsing the `results` is what I'm having a lot of trouble with.

Comment: `pd.json_normalize(data, 'results')` ? What output are you trying to get?

Comment: THANK YOU @HenryEcker - that is exactly what I needed to actually get some output that I can now work with.  Not sure why I thought I was supposed to be using `Series` for what I've been trying to do.